Belkin RT1800: does it allow wireless connections when in wireless bridge mode?
I have set it up as a wireless bridge, but it does not seem to broadcast any wireless network anymore.
I cannot find another SSID in my house.
My expectation was that the RT1800 would still broadcast its own Wi-Fi network with its own SSID, with the internet source being my original Wi-Fi network. Is that not the case ?

It depends. The answer is NO if the mode is "range extender" and YES if the mode is "AP (Access Point).

Thks for your reply - not relevant for this specific router as those "modes" are not available.

First off, I'm assuming you want the Belkin to act as a signal booster for rooms that get a weak signal from your primary router.
From the Belkin RT1800 user manual, page 11:

• Wireless Bridge
A wireless bridge wirelessly connects to your main router and can share the internet connection with devices connected to the bridge’s Ethernet ports.

So it would appear that when in wireless bridge mode the router only acts as a wireless client and does not re-broadcast an additional WiFi network. It only acts as a receiver and shares its connection to its ethernet ports.
That doesn't necessarily mean that it can't act as a signal booster (i.e. acting as a client and simultaneously broadcasting a separate network), but the user manual is very bare bones so I can't verify that. Try checking under Connectivity/Advanced Routing and WiFi/Advanced Settings.
Alternatively, if you are able to run an ethernet cable from your primary router to this one, you should be able to set it to "Bridge Mode" (not Wireless Bridge) and have it work as a second WiFi network, sharing its ethernet connection to your modem. Personally, I'd recommend doing this if this is a possibility - you'll get the strongest and most reliable connection this way.

Short of that, you can try installing third-party router firmware such as OpenWRT which allows you to do things the manufacturer's firmware can't, but I would NOT recommend that for the faint-of-heart. If you just bought the RT1800 and the two other options above don't work, then take it back to the store and look for a dedicated WiFi repeater instead. If your existing primary router has mesh capabilities, you can probably buy compatible mesh extenders which will work best.

Thanks for your reply - I have gone down the route of OpenWRT since wired connection to the main router is not possible. Think this will lead to lots of other questions because I cannot access the UI of the belkin anymore :)

Ok, best of luck. I'd recommend using the OpenWRT Forum for further questions.
